# Will my paper get an ISBN/ISSN number if I upload to arXiv.org?

Tags: conference, arxiv, online-publication, license

I want to upload my paper to arxiv.org. 
I also want to submit the same paper to a conference (computer science/multimedia related). The PC chair informed me that if the paper already has an ISBN/ISSN number, then it cannot be submitted to the conference.

Does arxiv, add an ISBN/ISSN number to all uploaded papers by default ? (assuming I choose the minimal, 'perpetual, non-exclusive' license option on arxiv)

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. ISBNs are assigned to published *books* (print or electronic), and ISSNs are assigned to published *journals* (or other serials, such as conference proceedings).

arXiv is not publishing either of these and so will not issue such identifiers.

This is effectively saying "if it's been published, it's not allowed, but informal circulation online or as a working paper is fine". Having an ISBN or ISSN is a simple (though of course not perfect) test to see if something counts as "properly" published. (It's worth noting that papers as such never get an ISSN - the serials they are published in have ISSNs but this will be common to all papers in that serial.)

Answer (score 5):

No, arXiv does not issue papers ISBN or ISSN numbers.  This is in keeping with the original and continuing function of the site as a preprint repository.  Much of the content that is initially posted on the arXiv goes on to be published elsewhere, and the initial arXiv posting is not considered publication in the usual sense.

At this point, any conference or journal ought to have a standard policy on arXiv submissions.  Many (essentially all, in the fields I am familiar with) venues explicitly allow authors to post preprints on the arXiv before (or after) they are published.  If you are not sure about the policy of the conference you are submitting to, just ask the organizer for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let us clarify that ISSN is a number associated to periodic journals (academic or not), magazines and etc. They can be distributed in printed versions or online, or both. No ISSN is given to an article.

With that said, **arXiv does have an ISSN indeed**, namely [2331-8422](https://portal.issn.org/resource/ISSN/2331-8422). The fact that it is an online repository to publish preprints does not disqualify it to have an ISSN. ISSN does not bring any kind of "quality control" for journals and magazines, it simply keeps registry of such periodicals. A  paper on arXiv is not considered "published" because arXiv is not a peer reviewed journal, and this indeed does not give much scientific value to it. But, in the strict sense of the word, all papers on arXiv can be said to have been published.

Papers individually can also have a digital identification through the [DOI](https://www.doi.org/) (digital object identification). In fact, any online publication of a platform that have ISSN may have a DOI. For instance, a blog can have a ISSN, and each one of its publications can have a DOI associated to it. The arXiv also attributes DOI numbers to every paper it publishes.

To finish, ISBN is an registry associated to book publications. Each country has a specific institute responsible to emit ISBN. You also don't need a publisher to give a ISBN to a book. I mean, if someone write a book it can individually ask for a ISBN (of course there are cost and some requirements to satisfy). Like ISSN, the ISBN is an international identification of books. Note that online books can also have a DOI number together with a ISBN.